# how to remove the error message when text is enetered

Tags: javascript

When I run the program, the error message appears, but when I type in a valid response, the error message is still there.  Following is my code.

```
var errorFoudFlag = 'N';

if (firstname.value === '');

    console.log(firstname.value);
    firstname_error.innerText = 'Please enter your name';

if (lastname.value === '');

    console.log(lastname.value);
    lastname_error.innerText = 'Please enter last name';

if (numpets.value === '');

    console.log(numpets.value);
    numpets_error.innerText = 'Please enter the number of pets you have'

if (errorFoudFlag == 'N');
```

When I type in name, the error message should disappear.

Comment: Updated code blocks and text for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the messages before starting the validations

```
var errorFoudFlag = 'N';
firstname_error.innerText = '';
lastname_error.innerText = '';
numpets_error.innerText = ''

if (firstname.value === '');

    console.log(firstname.value);
    firstname_error.innerText = 'Please enter your name';

if (lastname.value === '');

    console.log(lastname.value);
    lastname_error.innerText = 'Please enter last name';

if (numpets.value === '');

    console.log(numpets.value);
    numpets_error.innerText = 'Please enter the number of pets you have'

if (errorFoudFlag == 'N');
```

Better still have a function like `resetErrors()`